# How to format correct image access size?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import scipy.ndimage as ndi
>>> import PIL
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import skimage.io as io
>>> img1 = io.imread(di1)
>>> img1.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> print(img1.shape)
(1200, 1600, 3)
>>> plt.imshow(img1[1200,1600,3],interpolation='none',cmap='gray')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 1200 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1200
```

It seems the image size is not within the bounds of the program, is there any way to reformat the image size so that it does work?

Comment: Indexing your image (a NumPy array) like you are doing will return exactly one value.  Except that Python is zero-indexed, so you'd need to do ``img1[1199, 1599, 2]``.  But this is not what you want, since you'd like to see the entire image, not only one pixel.  So try `plt.imshow(img)` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I tried 'plt.imshow(img1)' instead however the pop up was blank and it returned 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'.

Comment: You don't say what `di1` is in the above code.  Please try something like: `img = io.imread('filename.jpg'); plt.imshow(img)`.  You can also see extensive tested code snippets in the scikit-image examples gallery.